# zfs on x86_64 on qemu on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, zfs, qemu

I find when you try to ask for help for a bizarre problem, somebody inevitably tells you to solve your problem a different way, or they want to know what problem you REALLY want to solve, so here's my entire story.

I want to run zfs on a raspberry pi 2 in a stable way.

I've been reading that some people have gotten zfs on linux to build on a raspberry pi but it's unstable because it relies heavily on virtual memory.

```
http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#WhyShouldIUseA64BitSystem
```

So I had a better idea. Why not run qemu, emulate a 64bit architecture, install some small linux distro and run zfs on that.

Sure it will be slow, but this is an experiment before I go spending money on a bigger machine.

But none of the 64 bit distros I've tried boot the kernel on qemu, they all get a kernel panic (though they get past grub) but the error scrolls by so quickly I can't tell what the problem is.

Has anybody gotten any x86_64 linux distro to run on a raspberry pi2?
Is there an option other than qemu that I can try?

Comment: Addendum, yes I have tried zfs fuse but it's lacking in some features I want and isn't solid enough for reliably use from my experience.

Comment: No no no no no no no. Emulating an x64 system on top of a Pi is certainly not going to make it work any better when it cannot run on the underlying hardware. The device does not have the RAM or CPU power to run it in any useable fashion. It won't just be slow, it literally *won't work*

Comment: That's an interesting point. The cpu will be slow, yes, and the memory will be limited sure (although I have lots of disk I can use for swap). I know zfs likes to use lots of memory for cache which swap will not help, but I don't think the situation is as dire as you make it out to be.

Comment: I mean, that's like 7 nos. And if I learned one thing about computers, it's never say never. Or no 7 times.

Comment: It's not so much that it's technically impossible to achieve but rather there's a significant chance either you or your equipment will die of old age before anything useful happens. More importantly, "Stable" and "A dozen of dirty hacks chained together just to get it to run" don't usually coexist. How exactly are you running qemu by the way, I suspect that's the root of the issue there. AFAIK qemu-system-x86_64 is the only fully software virtualizer for Linux.

Comment: that's the one. qemu x86_64 yields kernel panics on boot. sometimes it just hangs forever.